# Multi-level circuit simple NAND conversion: Why keep non-NAND symbols?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, logic-level

I am working on understanding the NAND conversion. I have just got the basics of two-level NAND conversion, and when I went to the book example for a multi-level NAND conversion it used solved an example until reaching to a level and kept the OR gate symbol, although he could replace it with NAND. I have searched on the web I found some people done the same but without reasoning why. I read the text book related-material but also the writer didn't explain why he left it.

The example is:

[image: (a) is the initial (b) is after simplifying (note the B')]

Why did he leave the OR gate symbols although he could replace them with NAND?

Comment: The two different symbols in the bottom diagram represent exactly the same gate -- a NAND gate.

Comment: i mean the 2nd and 4th levels (OR's) must be replaced with NAND why he left them @DaveTweed

Comment: That's the point -- those **are** NAND gates. Write out the truth table and you'll see this.

Comment: i know they are equivalent to NAND gate but why we don't put a NAND symbol instead ? @DaveTweed

Comment: @Andyaka the goal is repressent the equation using NAND's the first part repressented the equation as it is the secound supposed repressent it with NAND

Comment: We don't put the NAND symbol because it would make the diagram harder to read. Why do you think that this is a problem?

Comment: @DaveTweed from my opinion I might say it because we can visualize the De Morgan's Theorem if we kept it like this. however, really thanks to you i felt like i am getting the point now.

Comment: Anyway, I find it irritating that `B` of the first circuit changed into `B'` of the second circuit. First I thought this is an error... until I saw that little tiny tick. I would have inserted a NAND as inverter. -- Lesson to learn: Things done by humans tend to be inexplicable. ;-)

Comment: However, seeing the inverters at the output and at the input of the same wire demonstrates the correct transformation. The author could have added a third circuit where these input-inverted-OR symbols are replaced by NAND symbols.

Answer (score 2):

The two OR gates you see are negative logic, which has the same truth table as NAND. [DeMorgan's Theorem](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/boolean/demorgan.html) tells us so.

That is,

- Negative-logic (Demorgan) OR: Y = !A + !B

is the same as:

- positive-logic NAND: Y = !(A & B)

Work out the truth table for each, you will see that they are the same.

What the authors intent seems to be is to convey is that **if you have choices for the signal polarity** (notice in the second diagram they use B' and C', that is, negative-true inverted versions of them) then you can use Demorgan's Theorem to simplify your logic somewhat - if 'simplify' means use all NAND.

As to why they chose to represent the two OR gates as neg-logic OR instead of pos-logic NAND, they seem to want to show similarity in structure to the original logic. That is, those neg-logic ORs occupy the same  functional space as the pos-logic ORs in the original diagram.

In the bigger picture, **they're encouraging you to think about negative-logic and positive-logic representations of the same gate.**

By the way, the same DeMorgan conversion can be done using NOR (neg-logic AND), [as was famously done to build the Apollo Guidance Computer](https://www.righto.com/2019/09/a-computer-built-from-nor-gates-inside.html). That said, for CMOS there is area and leakage advantages that favor using NAND over NOR. More here: [Why is NAND gate preferred over NOR gate in industry?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/110649/why-is-nand-gate-preferred-over-nor-gate-in-industry)

However, real-world logic used in ASICs and other ICs won't use just one gate type, be it NAND or NOR. Instead, they will use a variety of structures provided by the standard cell library, including efficient and-or-invert (AOI) / or-and-invert (OAI), transmission gate types, as well as custom cells for critical and complex paths like RAMs, ALUs or multipliers. More here: [What is the lowest level of CPU programming above transistors?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/575289/what-is-the-lowest-level-of-cpu-programming-above-transistors/575299#575299)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

These two gates act as an NAND gate
example: lets consider gate 1 marked in the figure
lets take A as one input
B as other input

now, since there is a bubble input of or gate will become
A'  and B'

so, (A'+B')'
after simplification
it will be
=> (AB)'
This is nothing but NAND gate output

this is the reason in your image they are using or gates whose both inputs are complimented.

Comment: I think the question is asking why one would use OR gates instead of NAND in the sense that one presumably performs better than the other, and what is that reason?